# 'advanced' indexing question in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an indexing problem in Matlab. Let's say that I have a array $A$ with $m$-dimensions with $m$ **depending on the problem**. So $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times ... \times n_m}$

Suppose I have vector with indices $x = [i_2, ..., i_m]$ and I want to take the vector $A(:, i_2, ..., i_m)$. If $m$ is constant in all cases, it is not that difficult. You can just say $i_j = x(j), \forall j = 2, ..., m$. Is it possible to do this without an if-loop (so without saying 'if m == 2 then .. if m == 3 then ...' and so on ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not ask on stackexchange.com?

Comment: I was started there, but I can't write in Latex there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
% I assume you have an m dimensional A matrix, i.e. length(size(A)) == m,
% and an index vector i of size m-1
icell = num2cell(i);   % Tranform vector to cell
out = A(:, icell{:});  % It's very simple :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Albeit the code looks gruesome, you can construct the expression as a string and then use [eval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

```
str = ['A(:'];
for i = 2:m
  str = [str ', ' int2str(x(i-1))];
end
str = [str ')'];
v = eval(str); %gives the desired vector
```

Comment: Never use `eval`. It is considered to be a very bad habit

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for this case?

Comment: Never mind, I see yours now.

Comment: Matlab documentation's judgement is not as sweeping, offering only that `eval` ["is not always the best solution to a programming problem"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

Comment: Perhaps it is also a personal thing, but I would try to prevent it *at all costs*. It makes the code practically unreadable. Furthermore, Matlab has to compile the `eval` code when evaluated the `eval` statement, which makes it very slow

Comment: BTW, you are using a growing vector (`str`), which is something I would also prevent *at all costs* :P